# Dynamic handling of mongodb data

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, fusioncharts

My requirement is to generate charts using fusion charts.

I'm supposed to provide data to fusion charts from MongoDB which is a no SQL database.

MongoDB stores data into collections which is in the json format.and fusion charts accepts the data either in json format or in Xml format.

how should i provide the data to the fusion charts?

Currently I have written a java class to read the collection and put it into the .json file and I am passing this json file to the fusion charts(ie. a program written in html embedded with javascript)separately.I am stuck with the issue that how to call a java function from javascript?

Hence is there any other better alternative for this ??

Comment: What java function do you need to call from JS?

Comment: Please provide your code block related to your question. Because your question is too general which has issue , also there is a wrong approach calling java function from javascript. Instead of this Make an ajax call to your controller which produces json or xml.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it isn't an easy task. You must make a Java Web Application with a Servlet, REST service or whatever you want. Then you must deploy the application in an application server like Tomcat or JBoss, so your HTML+Javascript application is able to do request to your Java service.

You can't call a standalone Java class from an HTML+Javascript page.

I think you're trying to do something that you don't know anything about... and must read a lot about the subject.

Comment: this is the task assigned to me in my company

Answer (score 0):

> how should i provide the data to the fusion charts?

FusionCharts has specific data formats for different charts. So if you have got the data from your MongoDB you need to parse and create FusionCharts compatible JSON data. So any JSON data wont work.

I hope I am wrong in assuming that, you have already done so. Otherwise you really need to learn a lot about simple things about reading the basics of any library, you intend to work.

Comment: I have already parsed the mongodb collection and also I have json data which is required for creation of the charts.

Comment: If the chart has correctly rendered and you want to call a JAVA function from the page, consider using AJAX as suggested by Korkut. We are really not sure about the problem, try to be more specific.